# Angular 8 life cycle hook performance issue

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I'm working on an Angular app which has a series of input fields with interdependent values i:e a lot of the field values are percentages of values from earlier component fields.

I have a function *setPercentages()* which is where I calculate the values for different fields, call patchValue({}) on my reactive form element and assign the values into field components.

My trouble is setPercentages() is called from the ngAfterViewChecked() life cycle hook. While it works, I soon began to notice **(1)** any component with an assigned value is no longer editable, **(2)** it seems to slow the application and even my computer down due to the fact that the hook is always firing.

So, in the image below, notice in the console area the ngAfterViewChecked has fired over 4k times in no more than a minute. On the right, the deposit value component is continually reset to the calculated value as returned from the ngAfterViewChecked hook.

[image]

As I'm a bit new to Angular, I'm looking for advice on how best to reliably update the figures in my textfield in response to a change in a neighbouring field component. While ngAfterViewChecked does allow me to do this, the performance hit is extreme.

Comment: you shouldn't do calculations on a view lifecycle hook for this reason. can you call setPercantages() when the value of the inputs change using valueChanges observable on the input fields?

Comment: another thing you can do is use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and reduce the number of change detection cycles